# SharePoint webpart layout problem

Tags: development, web-part, layouts

I'm trying to create simple visual webpart what should list files multiple locations and allow user add new files. However, I have small layout problem:

[image]

[image]

Visual webpart takes too much space on page. How I can change webpart width? How I can force web part size example 400x200, etc?
Here is visual webparts ascx code:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="SPGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="2" GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#FF00EE" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lb1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Name") %></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="20%" BorderStyle="Dotted" /> <%--TESTING--%>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="20%" BorderStyle="Solid" /> <%--TESTING--%>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and here is my C# code:

```
using (Panel panel = new Panel())
            {
                // Creates Add button, which allows users upload more reports.
                LinkButton lBtnExcel = new LinkButton();
                lBtnExcel.Text = "ADD";
                lBtnExcel.CssClass = "PRAddExcel";
                lBtnExcel.PostBackUrl = url;
                panel.Controls.Add(lBtnExcel);

                // space..
                Label labelSpace = new Label();
                labelSpace.Text = "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;";
                panel.Controls.Add(labelSpace);

                // Creates button which opens DataAnalyzer adding page
                LinkButton lBtnDA = new LinkButton();
                lBtnDA.Text = "REMOVE";
                lBtnDA.CssClass = "PRAddDA";
                lBtnDA.PostBackUrl = dictionary["externalLink"] + "?Page=" + pageName;
                panel.Controls.Add(lBtnDA);

                // space..
                Label labelSpace2 = new Label();
                labelSpace2.Text = "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;" + "&nbsp;";
                panel.Controls.Add(labelSpace2);

                // Creates button which opens new site and show all reports.
                LinkButton lBtnSM = new LinkButton();
                lBtnSM.Text = "SHOW MORE";
                lBtnSM.CssClass = "ShowMore";
                lBtnSM.PostBackUrl = url + "/SitePages/AllReports.aspx?ShowAll=1&Page=" + pageName + "&OrgPage=" + orgPage;
                panel.Controls.Add(lBtnSM);
                Controls.Add(panel);
            }
```

I tried to change ascx code, but i cannot force width. It wont work.

Comment: You are setting an ID of SPGridView for the gridview, can't that be then used in CSS to set an appropriate width?

Comment: I tried to use external CSS-file and SPGridView ID, but it didn't work.
It's odd that I can change color in .ascx file but width do not work. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you put a width on the gridview itself? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview_properties.aspx, like Width="350"